# Can Magento pull in USPS "Paid Online" rates rather than "Post Office" rates?

Tags: api, magento, usps

We have USPS rates displaying correctly in Magento 1.5. However, we have noticed that the rates that are appearing are "Paid at Post Office" Rates, as opposed to "Paid Online" Rates.

It would be really nice to know if there is a way to change something so that Magento pulls in the "Paid Online" rates as they are cheaper for the customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module just needs to be adjusted so it passes Online instead of All in the  tag.